# Why does this always give the output 0 0 0?

Tags: python-3.x

For some reason I'm not able to change the global variable `total_hours`. Or why is the output always `0 0 0`?

```
hour = 1
day = 24
week = 168
part_day = 8
total_hours = int(0)
hours = total_hours % 168
days = ((total_hours % 168) // 7)
weeks = total_hours // 168

def sleep():
        global total_hours
        global week
        total_hours += week

def show_time():
        global hours
        global days
        global weeks
        print(hours, days, weeks)

sleep()

show_time()
```

Comment: You never changed the value of `hours`, `days`, or `weeks`.  All you changed is `total_hours`.  The variables are assigned to values, not to fractions of `total_hours`.

Comment: But if i change the value of total_hours itself it works...

Comment: If you change it before you create the other variables, yes.  If I call you Eric and tell my neighbor to give Eric something, he will give it to you.  If, before I tell him that, I tell him that my brother is Eric, he will give the thing to my brother, not you.  If I tell him *afterwards* that my brother is Eric, that won't change what he already did.  You still won't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do here is the following:

1. You assign the value `0` to the variable `total_hours`
2. You calculate the values for the variables `hour`, `days` and `week` by using the variable `total_hours` with the value `0` and assign the results to them too
3. You change the value of the variable `total_hours`
4. You print the values of `hour`, `days` and `weeks` like they were calculated in 2

To better understand what's happening you should play a little bit more with `print`:

```
hour = 1
day = 24
week = 168
part_day = 8
total_hours = int(0)
hours = total_hours % 168
days = ((total_hours % 168) // 7)
weeks = total_hours // 168

def sleep():
        global total_hours
        global week
        total_hours += week

print 'values before `sleep`', hours, days, weeks, total_hours
sleep()
print 'values after `sleep`', hours, days, weeks, total_hours
```

If you want to (re)calculate the values depend on `total_hours` you could do something like this:

```
hour = 1
day = 24
week = 168
part_day = 8
total_hours = int(0)
hours = total_hours % 168
days = ((total_hours % 168) // 7)
weeks = total_hours // 168

def recalc():
    global weeks, days, hours, total_hours
    hours = total_hours % 168
    days = ((total_hours % 168) // 7)
    weeks = total_hours // 168

def sleep():
    global total_hours, week
    total_hours += week

def show_time():
    global hours, days, weeks
    print(hours, days, weeks)

sleep()
recalc()
show_time()
```